# NGINX JavaScript module with a session storage (like Redis)

Tags: javascript, nginx, redis

I know there is a possibility to process each request via a JS script right inside the NGINX server.

I know there is the Lua Nginx module and the Lua Redis driver, and it's possible to write a script in Lua and use Redis right from the NGINX server.

However, I want to use standard functionality of NGINX and I prefer to code in JS. I wonder is it possible to use some session storage with the NJS? And how to do it? Particularly, I would like to use Redis as a session storage.

Answer (score 4):

If one avoids to compile and install third-party modules for Nginx himself, I suppose the best way to build session storage with njs and Redis is to utilize the builtin [ngx_http_upstream_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) module and set up something like that

```
http {
    [...]

    upstream redis {
        server unix:/var/run/redis/nginx.sock;
    }

    [...]

    js_path conf.d/js/;

    js_import redismiddleware.js;

    [...]

    server {
        [...]

        location /redisadapter {
            internal;

            try_files @dummy @redis;
        }

        location /request-we-are-tracking-no-1/ {
            js_content redismiddleware.processRequestConditional;
        }

        [...]

        location /request-we-are-tracking-no-2/ {
            js_content redismiddleware.processRequestUnconditional;
        }

        [...]
    }
```

and the corresponding script

```js
var queryString = require('querystring')

function processRequestConditional (request) {
    request.subrequest('/redisadapter', {
        method : 'POST',
        body : queryString.stringify({
          /* data to transfer to Redis */
        })
    }).then(function (response) {
        var reply = {}

        /**
         * parsing and checking feedback from Redis, 
         * saving some data from feedback to reply 
         * object, doing any things as planned, 
         * running any additional routines et 
         * cetera 
         */
        
       if (/* Redis reply is OK */) {
           return reply;
       } else {
           throw new Error('Because we don`t like you!')
       }
    }).then(function (data) {
        /**
         * Making one more subrequest to obtain the content
         * the client is waiting for
         */

         request.subrequest('/secret-url-with-content').then(
            (response) => request.return(response.httpStatus, response.body)
         )
    }).catch((error) {
        /** 
         * Returning to client with response "There will be
         * be no response"
         */
        request.return(403, error.message)
    })
}

function processRequestUnconditional (request) {
    request.subrequest('/redisadapter', {
        method : 'POST',
        body : queryString.stringify({
          /* data to transfer to Redis */
        })
    }).then(function (response) {
        /**
         * parsing and checking feedback from Redis,
         * doing some things, running some or other
         * additional routines depending on reply
         */
    })

    request.subrequest('/secret-url-with-content').then(
        (response) => request.return(response.httpStatus, response.body)
    )
}

export default { processRequestConditional, processRequestUnconditional }
```

Short summary

1. Redis is listening and replying on socket
   `/var/run/redis/nginx.sock`
2. Virtual internal location `/redisadapter` receives the requests from njs script, transfers them to Redis and returns the replies back to njs method, which started the requests sequense
3. To establish data exchange with Redis on some location, we take control over Nginx standard flow and maintain these locations with custom njs methods
4. Thus, the code in methods in addition to Redis related information exchange routines should itself implement the complete subroutine of retrieving the requested content and delivering this content back to client, since we took this job from Nginx
5. This is achieved by sets of local subrequests from server to server, which are transparent for clients. njs method completes the set and itself delivers the requested content back to the client
6. The above example contains two methods, processRequestConditional and processRequestUnconditional, with the goal to show the most used alternative logic ways to maintain such kind of tasks
7. The first one, processRequestConditional, demonstrates subrequests chain - i.e., the content, requested by client, won't be obtained, until njs method is busy with its primary task transferring the next piece of data into Redis session storage. Moreover, if the script is not satisfied with Redis feedback, the request of content for client is skipped at all, and the client faces refusal message instead
8. The second method, processRequestUnconditional, transfers the data to Redis storage the same way as the first one above, but this time the fate of the client's request does not depend on results of Redis feedback, thus the secondary request for content is issued at the same time with primary, and flows in parallel while script continue the information exchange round with session storage

Of course, my brief explanation leaves a lot of details behind the scenes, but I hope the basic concept is now clear

Feel free to ask additional questions